# how to debug python-twisted ipdb

Tags: python, twisted, ipdb

Is there a way to run interactive debugger inside a twisted app?

```
  import ipdb;ipdb.set_trace()
```

this resolve in:

```
7-02-03T22:25:49+0100 [stderr#error] Traceback (most recent call last):
2017-02-03T22:25:49+0100 [stderr#error]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
2017-02-03T22:25:49+0100 [stderr#error]     self.run()
2017-02-03T22:25:49+0100 [stderr#error]   File "bo/OLA_test.py", line 110, in run
2017-02-03T22:25:49+0100 [stderr#error]     self.wrapper.Run()
2017-02-03T22:25:49+0100 [stderr#error]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ola/ClientWrapper.py", line 278, in Run
2017-02-03T22:25:49+0100 [stderr#error]     self._ss.Run()
2017-02-03T22:25:49+0100 [stderr#error]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ola/ClientWrapper.py", line 197, in Run
2017-02-03T22:25:49+0100 [stderr#error]     self._CheckTimeouts(now)
2017-02-03T22:25:49+0100 [stderr#error]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ola/ClientWrapper.py", line 222, in _CheckTimeouts
2017-02-03T22:25:49+0100 [stderr#error]     event.Run()
2017-02-03T22:25:49+0100 [stderr#error]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ola/ClientWrapper.py", line 67, in Run
2017-02-03T22:25:49+0100 [stderr#error]     self._callback()
2017-02-03T22:25:49+0100 [stderr#error]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/bdb.py", line 49, in trace_dispatch
2017-02-03T22:25:49+0100 [stderr#error]     return self.dispatch_line(frame)
2017-02-03T22:25:49+0100 [stderr#error]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/bdb.py", line 68, in dispatch_line
2017-02-03T22:25:49+0100 [stderr#error]     if self.quitting: raise BdbQuit
```

with 
Twisted==16.6.0

Answer (score 0):

You just need to keep stdin and stdout attached to something useful.  Make sure you don't daemonize and tell the logging system *not* to screw with stdio.

Alternatively, you can use a debugger that doesn't require stdin and stdout.  For example, with `pudb`:

```
import pudb.remote
pudb.remote.set_trace()
```

Also, you didn't ask, but multiprocessing and Twisted are mostly incompatible.  It's possible to get them to work reliably together with great, great care - but there are usually easier ways to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for reply, could you please explain why they are incompatible? I've used them togheter to share information between different process and  the script is running since 124 days.

Comment: You can find a bunch of questions on the topic by searching SO for "[twisted] [multiprocessing]".  Here's one in particular: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11272874/is-twisted-incompatible-with-multiprocessing-events-and-queues